# Form.io AngularJS Setting 'options'

Tags: angularjs, formio

I am using form.io (angular JS) to create a form using a JSON object. Also using the 'wizard' mode.
This works well, but i just cant seem to understand how to set the options for the form.
Specifically the breadcrumbSettings.clickable setting, which i need to set to false.

I am creating the form in the HTML like this:

```
<formio form="formCtrl.formio" submission="submission" ></formio>
```

I tried setting the 'options' param in the html/JS/accessing the form object. Nothing works.
And i cant find a relevant example for setting the options object using angular js.

Anyone out there knows how to achieve this?

Thanks,
Guy

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation you have to pass formio-options attribute to the above formtag.

Documentation link: https://github.com/formio/ngFormio/wiki/Formio-Directive

example: `<formio src="currentForm" formio-options="{skipQueue: true}"></formio>`

You would have to pass json of options applicable to formio here in formio tag.

Here some more link from documentation from official repository: https://github.com/formio/help.form.io/blob/49f570dab40edc87234cc06f4dd833aa7aa03561/_paragraphs/developer/offline/offlineapi.md#request-options